# Не переведены два пункта в меню "справка"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Вот они:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за замечание! Поправил. Строки будут доступны после ближайшего развертывания сборки.